# ContextualVersionConflict Error with PyJWT on installing djangorestframework-simplejwt

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, pyjwt

I have a digital ocean django instance and after I installed `djangorestframework-simplejwt`, I am getting Contextual Version Conflict with following error message:

`(PyJWT 1.7.1 (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('pyjwt<3,>=2'), {'djangorestframework-simplejwt'})`

I have upgraded `PyJwt` to 2+ version and have also removed existing `python3-jwt` from the instance but with no success. Not sure how and where this 1.7 version is coming from.  I have also upgraded the django version to 3+

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this conflicting issue with 'djangorestframework-simplejwt' ('pyjwt<3,>=2') when trying to install the Twilio library. I solved it by removing the Twilio version of the requirements.txt file